# Who are the twelve Egyptian gods?

Tags: egyptian, pantheon

Herodotus mentions an Egyptian *Dodekatheon* in Book 2:

> The Egyptians, they went on to affirm, first brought into use the names of the twelve gods, which the Greeks adopted from them; and first erected altars, images, and temples to the gods; and also first engraved upon stone the figures of animals. In most of these cases they proved to me that what they said was true. And they told me that the first man who ruled over Egypt was Min, and that in his time all Egypt, except the Thebaic canton, was a marsh, none of the land below Lake Moeris then showing itself above the surface of the water. This is a distance of seven days' sail from the sea up the river.
>
> ...
>
> Again, the Egyptians disclaim all knowledge of the names of Neptune and the Dioscuri, and do not include them in the number of their gods; but had they adopted the name of any god from the Greeks, these would have been the likeliest to obtain notice, since the Egyptians, as I am well convinced, practised navigation at that time, and the Greeks also were some of them mariners, so that they would have been more likely to know the names of these gods than that of Hercules. But the Egyptian Hercules is one of their ancient gods. Seventeen thousand years before the reign of Amasis, the twelve gods were, they affirm, produced from the eight: and of these twelve, Hercules is one.
>
> <sub>Source: Book 2. The History of Herodotus. Translated by George Rawlinson</sub>

The eight older gods are the [Ogdoad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogdoad_(Egyptian)). Who are the twelve younger ones?

Comment: These are twelve gods indeed. Any indication these are the ones Herodotus had in mind?